# What does ls -Rm/ do versus ls aside from adding in commas?

Tags: unix, terminal

I'm trying to learn Unix and can't figure out what ls -Rm does.

Answer (score 1):

From [the output of `man ls`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html), `-R` means "list subdirectories recursively", and `-m` means "fill width with a comma separated list of entries". I assume the `/` in your title was a typo, as it's not a valid option and will make the command not work at all.